# Window Listener and Action Listener in one class JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener, windowlistener

I have program in java, and there is GUI. I have to create action and window listeneres for few frames. I create one listener class for every frame. Like this:

```
public class Listener implements ActionListener, WindowListener {

  HERE ALL NEEDED METHODS BY THIS TWO INTERFACES
}
```

And my question is that it is good solution? Or I should create two separate classes for this? I create it in one class because I have only few lines of code in methods from WindowListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good solution, if you are respecting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

If you want to do the same thing on action event and window event, one single class is a good choice.

Example:

```
public class LoggerListener implements ActionListener, WindowListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       logger.log("Action performed!");
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        logger.log("Window opened!");
    }

}
```

But if you want to do different things (log when action is performed and show a message when some window is opened, for example), is much better to create two different classes. One could extend `WindowAdapter` and the other could implement `ActionListener`.

Answer (score -1):

I probably would do:

```
public class Listener extends WindowAdapter implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Less lines of code, as you not forced to implement all `WindowListener` methods.